# How can I show this function is Weakly Sequentially Lower Semicontinuos?

Tags: analysis

Suppoe $X$ is a Banach spaces and $G\subset X$ is a convex open set. Let $\phi:G\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a $C^1$ function and assume that $\phi'$ is a bounded and peseudo-monotone map (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/215120/pseudo-monotone-operator/262314#262314) for a definiton of pseudo-monotone).

We say that $\phi$ is weakly sequentially lower semicontinuos (WSLSC) in $G$ if for every sequence $x_n$ in $G$ which converges weakly to $x\in G$ we have that $$\phi(x)\leq\liminf \phi(x_n)$$

How can i show that $\phi$ is WSLSC?