# Is there a Geometrical Interpretation for Pseudo-Monotonicity?

Tags: analysis

Suppose $X$ is a real Reflexive  Banach space and $f:X\rightarrow X^\star$ a pseudo-monotone map (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/215120/pseudo-monotone-operator) for a definition of pseudo-monotone). Is there a geoemetric interpretation for this definition.

For example, we know that a differentiable $f: X: \rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is convex if and only if $f':X\rightarrow X^\star$ is monotone.  From this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/265622/how-can-i-show-this-function-is-weakly-sequentially-lower-semicontinuos) we know that with the additional condition of boundedness $f$ is  WSLSC. Can we deduce more about the geometry of $f$?

I know that the first one to define the notion of pseudo-monotonicity was Brezis. Does anyone know the paper there he first defined it?